# NPM package-lock version property

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

Is there a way to manage/sync the version property in package-lock.json file? my situation is as follow:

1. When I have a new release, I manually update the version property in
   `package.json`, commit and push.
2. On the build server, `npm install` to get all the deps needed by the build server, etc..
3. However, `npm install` also update the version property in `package-lock.json` to match the one in package.json (which is good but too late).

I could have made an `npm install` in the first step to get the version property in `package-lock.json` in-sync with the one in `package.json` then commit and push, but for me this does not make sense (not the purpose of `npm install`, someone can simply forget, etc..) . I also know that I should not be manually updating the package-lock.json file.

- Is there a better way to handle this ?
- I'm using NPM version **5.6** and I know in version **5.7** there is a new command `npm ci` which does not alter `package-lock.json` file but also does not solve the fact that the version needs to be synced, and anyway for now I would like to know if there is a way to handle this in version 5.6.

Comment: Does `npm install --package-lock-only` before commit makes more sense?

P.s. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version

Comment: if you change the version number to '*' in the package.json file means automatically it take the latest version. but evertime you need to install the package manually

Comment: @Vinoth I cannot change the version number to '*' I use the version to display it on the UI.

Comment: @wanjas what does --package-lock-only do exactly ? but still does not make sense since you have to do an ```npm install``` anyway.

Comment: @mkhayata
Generally editing package.json manually should be discouraged.
You can make use of npm commands which will update both package.json and package-lock.json.        

`npm install <package-name@version> --save` and
`npm uninstall <package-name@version>  --save`

Comment: @SreeraghAR this does not address the issue I have, this will update particular packages' version, not the app version. Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the answer is "npm version [new version]". Which will update package.json, package-lock.json and npm-shrinkwrap.json.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-version